# YSlow always tells me my content is not served from a CDN

Tags: cdn, yslow

YSlow always tells me my content is not served from a CDN no matter what value(s) I put in about:config extensions.yslow.cdnHostnames.

I've tried entering my.cdn.com, http://my.cdn.com/folder1/a/b/, http://my.cdn.com basically every variation I could think of and no matter what values I configure it never acknowledges it's hosted on a CDN.

Is this just a giant bug in YSlow or is there some kind of specified format that's not explained anywhere that it wants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try restarting firefox after you change the setting.

For me, I specified the domain name as "cdn.ourdomain.com" - no http://. Then, when I ran yslow, it showed:

```
Using these CDN hostnames from your preferences: cdn.ourdomain.com
```

but it was ignoring the setting. Restarting firefox and rerunning yslow seemed to do the trick.

Comment: This definitely explains alot as I would repeatedly change the values and not see any immediate results, I haven't verified this fully but I don't think I'm going to far out on a branch to accept this now. If it doesn't seem to matter I'll post again.

Answer (score 2):

i've had the same problem, yslow required you to add the hostname only

http://cdn.example.com will not work, although cdn.example.com will do fine.. at least for me :)